# How can I select elements living in a certain range of the DOM hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a DOM element `C` which is a descendant of DOM element `A`.  There are several layers between them, one of which is an class of element named `B`.

If I have `jQuery("#A")` and `jQuery("#C)`, how can I find the parent element of `C` with class `B`, which is also a descendant of `A`?

If I use `parents()` of `C` then I could potentially get any elements with class `B` which are above `A`, which I do not want.  If I use `find()` of `A` then I could get elements below `C`, which I do not want.

The number of layers between each of the elements I am interested in is not known.  While the example shows a single layer, which would allow me to do `.children().children()`, I can't be certain that it's only 2 levels away.

e.g.

```
...
<div id="A">
 <div>
   <div class="B">
     <div>
       <div id="C">...</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this situation, you need [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('#C').closest('.B') // would get the closest parent(.B) of a child(#C)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#C').closest('.B').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('#A').length;
});
```

You dont need the filter if you know that the closest div.B will always be below #A